# Upload file more than 500mb size

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue in my application.I have file with 200mb size. I want to give user access of uploading files with size up to 500mb. My config file has following setting for uploading file request.

```
  <httpRuntime
      executionTimeout="7200"
      maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
```

Still if i am uploading file with size of up to 200mb connection disrupt.I suppose i have already mention 2 hour limit in config.

Can anyone let me know the best and simplest way to upload file with huge size (Up to 500mb) ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question for possibilities http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692184/large-file-uploading-to-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that the HTTP protocol is made for this scenario. IMHO I would do this over FTP.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Let me check some alternative also.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is for IIS6 and does not affect IIS7 in case you are using the latter. If this is the case, you should adjust this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="SIZE IN KB"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The default value is 30000000, less than 30Mb.

See more information in [the IIS page about requestLimits](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits).